# What's the real size of the launcher icon on nexus 5?

Tags: android, nexus-5

As [the doc](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#launcher) mentioned,the launcher icon is 48*48dp.

So I think the launcher icon should be 144 * 144px on my nexus 5.
But I research a screenshot of my nexus 5,I find it's almost 166* 163px.
Why it's bigger than 144*144px?

### Is my method of calculating the size wrong?

(p.s. an app with a 144*144px icon in the drawable-xxhdpi folder is also shows 166* 163px in the launcher.)

[image]

This is my screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the [info](https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/EURexV9yF32) provided by someone working at Google, Nexus 5's launcher uses the launcher icon in the next DPI bucket, i.e. on Nexus 5 it will use one DPI bucket up XXHDPI --> XXXHDPI, which makes the icon 192x192. The reason why your measurement is less than 192 is because the launcher icon graphics is not supposed to fill the whole image.

Answer (score -3):

Nexus 5 is XXHDPI device.These device DPI are around 440. So, Google Nexus 5 need to add a 144*144px icon in the `drawable-xxhdpi` folder.

Comment: My puzzle is I find the size is bigger than 144*144px on my nexus 5.

Comment: are you put icon in drawable-xxhdpi? 

check that From which drawable folder , nexus 5 take icon.

Comment: Did you understand my last answer?

Comment: It's not it is xxxhdpi and so is nexus 4. Cheers. Feel free to remove this answer or o update it to nit confuse pp