# Mipmaps vs. drawable folders

Tags: android, android-drawable, mipmaps

I'm working with Android Studio 1.1 Preview 1. I noticed that when I create a new project I'm getting the following hierarchy:

[image]

Mipmap folders for different DPIs, no more different DPIs drawable folders.

Should I put all my resources in the mipmap folders, or just the app icon?

Comment: Check out this statement from the google blog spot link below :-
 "... because they are used at resolutions different from the device’s current density. For example, an xxxhdpi app icon can be used on the launcher for an xxhdpi device."
This tells that some devices explicitly tries to use icons of different density rather than what current device density specifies. eg. some manufacturer might like to use bigger icons in the home screen than launcher screen, or smaller icons for notifications than than usual specification. We must thus identify such resources and place them in mipmap folders.

Comment: The above comment is just an assumption on what I understand and might be wrong.

Comment: There is quite a lot more info over here -->  [mipmap drawables for icons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935810/mipmap-drawables-for-icons)

Comment: Google should add a Lint quick-fix for putting app-icons there. I've made a post about it here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219500

Answer (score 952, accepted):

The mipmap folders are for placing your app/launcher icons (which are shown on the homescreen) in only. Any other drawable assets you use should be placed in the relevant drawable folders as before.

According to [this Google blogpost](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html):

> It’s best practice to place your app icons in **mipmap-** folders (not the drawable- folders) because they are used at resolutions different from the device’s current density.

When referencing the **mipmap-** folders ensure you are using the following reference:

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

The reason they use a different density is that some launchers actually display the icons larger than they were intended. Because of this, they use the next size up.

Comment: To clarify, the "app icons" in the quoted section are referring to launcher icons, not necessarily other icons.

Comment: "because they are used at resolutions different from the device’s current density" what does this mean really? That's one of the most cryptic phrases in this release.

Comment: When you are using them in your code make sure you are using (R.mipmap.icon_name) not (R.drawable.icon_name).

Comment: @southerton When a resource from *drawable* is requested, a bitmap is chosen from the folder that matches the current density. For example, the Nexus 5 chooses drawables from XXHDPI. The launcher may choose an icon from a different folder. The Nexus 5 launcher uses icons from XXXHDPI. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25131077/whats-the-real-size-of-the-launcher-icon-on-nexus-5

Comment: @southerton The reason they use a different density is that some launchers actually display the icons larger than they were intended. Because of this, they use the next size up.

Comment: What if I am using some images in my application which should change its size according to the pixel density of device? Should I place them in mipmaps or drawables? Please advice.

Comment: I have a question. I have put all the appropriate images in all the appropriate folders, but when I try to make an `ImageView` with the `android:src = "@drawable/myimg"/>, I get cannot resolve. Do I need the image to also be in the drawable folder as well as the sub folders? I have been stuck on this for the last 4 and a half hours,  thanks for your help!

Comment: @NullPointer try `@mipmap/myimg` instead - as per comment #1 by Asthme.

Comment: To be simple, Android system can take a bitmap in mipmap regardless of the screen resolution of the device where your app is installed. For example mipmap-xxxhdpi qualifier will provide launcher icon that can appear larger than usual on an xxhdpi device.

Comment: can we choose different resolutions maually.. example xxxhdpi

Comment: any specific purpose to keep this new pattern where we already had **/drawable-XXX/** to defined these?? Any one !!

Comment: Where does it say that other images should be in drawable folder? What does the launchers do in order to get a different density of the icons? Isn't Mipmap a way to scale the images better, by combining them or something?

Comment: @joel menu, tab, bottom and navigation drawer icons should go to `mipmap` or `drawable`?

Comment: what if i have scalable vector graphic? that can be resized to any resolution so there is no need for specifying resolution