# Cannot resolve symbol @drawable/ic_launcher

Tags: android

I have an `ImageView` in my layout, see below code. When I'm trying to set the `src` attribute to be my launcher icon, I get the following error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol '@drawable/ic_launcher'
```

ic_launcer.png is added to my drawables folder, see below image. Why can I not reference my image in my `ImageView`?

Project structure:

[image: Project structure]

Layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Change(you have no drawable folders):**

```
@drawable/ic_launcher
```

**To(you are using mipmap folders):**

```
@mipmap/ic_launcher
```

**mipmaps** - used for icons only - [mipmap vs drawable folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065267/mipmap-vs-drawable-folders)

**drawables** - used for images other than icons

According to this [Google blogpost](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html):

> It’s best practice to place your app icons in mipmap- folders (not the
>   drawable- folders) because they are used at resolutions different from
>   the device’s current density.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the difference between the `drawable` and `mipmap` folders.

Answer (score 4):

your `drawable` are inside `mipmap`, which should be used to  app-launcher. If you want to use it as drawable you should copy those inside one of the `drawable/` folders

Comment: I see that now, must have been changed when I updated Android Studio. Is there any easy way to copy them to my (just created) drawable folder? `ctrl + c` and `ctrl + v` doesn't seem to work inside AS. Do I have to do it with file explorer?

Comment: it works on mac. If you are not on windows, use the shell.. it is the quickest way

Comment: @Marcus, [shift] + [f6] to quickly rename the folders. Mipmaps are the new way of doing drawables.

Comment: I ended up referencing it as `@mipmap/ic_launcher` as suggested by @JaredBurrows. +1 for your efforts tho, thanks.

Comment: check the documentation about `mipmap`. its behavior is slightly different from `drawable`. You are welcome

Comment: @JaredBurrows Not entirely true! Mipmap are the new way of doing launchers and other resources you might need in other densities. Mostly just launchers.

Comment: I will remember that, thanks for the help! Is it considered wrong to add my other drawables to the `mipmap` folder? As @Blackbelt stated, "mipmap [...] should be used to for app-launcher" @JaredBurrows

Comment: @Lamorak That is true but he **only** has launchers in his photo from his question.

Comment: It is not considered wrong, you'll just get different behavior. Basically best fitting resource will be chosen from `mipmap` folders for your ImageView, instead of picking the image marked for your density from corresponding `drawable` folder.