# @drawable and FrameLayout don't work in Android Studio and an error icon is shown

Tags: android, android-studio

**QUESTION 1**

Do you have any idea for how to fix this error?

[image]

**QUESTION 2**

My Activity's layout has worked pretty fine with Android API <=20. But with Android 5.1.1, the FrameLayout holding Button and Progress Bar does not work. The progressBar isn't shown.

Any helps are welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Well, what does the error say?

Comment: Did you refresh your project ? Build -> Clean Project

Comment: I did refreshed, i changed sdkTarget   (  targetSdkVersion 23) @Lazai

Comment: just clean your project. another solution:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243121/cannot-resolve-symbol-drawable-ic-launcher

Comment: @NiceLogics ,. wondering if this is from android studio.. No error in my drawable.xml

Comment: i think so, after an update.. android studio dosen't show any drawable

Comment: @NiceLogics , yeah, i just updated mine yesterday

Comment: @hatboy a new update on air that resolve this issue (just updated). bye.

Comment: @NiceLogics which did you updated because , i just updated one support repo but the error is still there?

Comment: @NiceLogics.. still waiting

Comment: android studio 1.4 build AI-141.2288178

Comment: Same, but mine still there