# Unable to add image to splash screen in android studio, getting error on build

Tags: android

So I am trying to add an image under the text at the splash screen but I get this error when I build the app
**Error:(26, 22) String types not allowed (at 'src' with value 'drawable/appimage.jpg').**

```
    <ImageView
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="345dp"
    android:src="drawable/appimage.jpg"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout="@+id/imageview"
    />
```

If I remove the image code , I don't get any error. Here is My splash activity code

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        final Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();
                synchronized (this) {
                    try {
                        wait(2000);

                        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                        finish();

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

I am a newbie android studio user so references for further learning shall be highly appreciated.

Comment: Solution: Remove .jpg or .png and it will work, if doesn't just refractor and rename and try again without file extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code...you have to rename your image  goto `drawable>yourimage>File>Refactor>Rename.`

```
 android:src="drawable/appimage"
```

Comment: Great, it worked, Without refractor, just removed the file extension .jpg

Comment: @DanielS you are welcome..try to rename alway using  `Refactor>Rename` this will be safe..

Comment: yeah I had already refracted it but was trying with extension, Will follow this protocol from now onwards. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Set the src in ImageView like this:

```
android:src="@drawable/appimage"
```

You have misspelled drawable, and the `.jpg` should be removed.

```
android:src="drawable/appimage.jpg" //no path to go to
```

Edit - You also don't have to explicitly give the file extension to when referring to any file in resources folder.

Comment: Sorry that is a typo while posting here , I have not misspelled it, 
When I add Your code, I get "cannot resolve symbol"

Comment: Please check again

Comment: If I put @drawable/appimage.jpg I get the error can not resolve..... If I don't put @ I get the error at build mentioned in the original post.

Comment: Check your drawable folder. Is the image actually there?

Comment: Yes it is, I refactored it and renamed it but still the same

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243121/cannot-resolve-symbol-drawable-ic-launcher

Comment: Actually I have both folders, mimmap and drawable and the image I am using is in drawable

Comment: I tried this as well  "File" -> "Invalidate Caches...", and select "Invalidate and Restart" option to fix this.

but still the same error

Comment: My bad. That was a silly point. You never declare extensions in pointing to resources. Though the original error as mentioned in OP was because of typo in `drawable`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
      android: background="@drawable/appimage.jpg"
```

And give the color in view group

```
      android:background="@color/black"
```

layout or liner layout what ever you have