# Android Studio - Button Size

Tags: android, xml, size, android-relativelayout, imagebutton

I am needing help importing a button in the ImageButton with a small size, because whenever I add the image to the image button, it always stays too big, and I also updated to the new Android Studio, which instead of the drawable folder, it has a mipmap folder instead.

Comment: For the size of the imageButton just change your layout width and height to some specific values. The mipmap folder is meant for your app icon only, read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065267/mipmap-vs-drawable-folders

Comment: OK, thanks. But also I noticed if you change the image asset, will it make it smaller, like the icon size?

Comment: Because that's what I did, and it seemed to make it not as big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It will stretch the image on the button to what ever the button size is.

```
<ImageButton
 android:width = "xx"
 android:height = "xx"
 android:src = "@drawable/xxx"
 android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```