# Android Studio keeps creating icons on drawable folder (isn't to be in mipmap?)

Tags: android, android-studio

The title says it all. Until then I did not know this convention using the mipmap folder to design icons. Finally, by using the wizard for creating icons in the IDE "Image Asset", Android Studio itself creates the 5 icons variations (`hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi`) in mipmap folder... But only makes him the type of asset is launcher icon, if "action bar and tab icons" icon is created in the drawable folder. That's right? It's some kind of bug? [What is the standard for mipmap and drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28065664/939803)?

Example:

[image: mipmap_and_drawable]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> That's right?

Yes.

> It's some kind of bug?

No.

> What is the standard for mipmap and drawable?

Well, there are two:

- Original Standard That Is Still Fine for 99.9% of Apps: ignore `mipmap` and use `drawable` for everything
- Google's New Poorly-Documented Standard: your launcher icons go in `mipmap`, while all other drawables go in `drawable`.

Comment: Understood but, an ordinary and simple icon, fits into what option: Launcher icons, Action Bar and Tab Icons Icons and Notifications?

Comment: @FilipeManuel: None of them. Of the three, "Action Bar and Tab Icons" is the most general-purpose.