# Can I delete the folder drawable in Android when my minimum API is 21?

Tags: android

I read some document, it seems that that mipmap replace drawable when  minimum API is 21.

1. Can I delete the folder drawable ?
2. There are only four folder mipmap-hdpi,mipmap-mdpi,mipmap-xhdpi and mipmap-xxhdpi when I generate a new project with Android Studio V1.3,  do I need add a folder **mipmap** for store normal picture and other resources?

BTW, there is a file border_ui.xml in the folder drawable in my a project, can I remove the file from the folder **drawable** to **mipmap**?

**border_ui.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <stroke android:width="0.8dp" android:color="#000000" />

    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp" />

</shape>
```

[image]

Comment: mipmap folders are only for the app icon (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065267/mipmap-vs-drawable-folders)

Comment: But, It's Ok if I place other png files to the folder  mipmap

Comment: No. mipmap is only for the launcher icons. You should put your drawables in drawable folders. Just create a bunch of them under res folder (drawable, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi and so forth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**drawable**/

For bitmap files (PNG, JPEG, or GIF), 9-Patch image files, and XML files that describe Drawable shapes or Drawable objects that contain multiple states (normal, pressed, or focused). See the Drawable resource type.

**mipmap**/

For app launcher icons. The Android system retains the resources in this folder (and density-specific folders such as mipmap-xxxhdpi) regardless of the screen resolution of the device where your app is installed. This behavior allows launcher apps to pick the best resolution icon for your app to display on the home screen. For more information about using the mipmap folders, see Managing Launcher Icons as mipmap Resources.

[See details by click here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/tools/projects/index.html#ApplicationModules)