# Android,adding an image asset

Tags: android, image, assets

when ever i add a image asset in drawable,i get those images in mipmap folder.And what is the difference between mipmap and drawable and why i am facing this problem.I have tried adding image asset in drawable and res folder.

Comment: How do you add them? And do you want a large image or a small icon?

Comment: Answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28065664/1575195

Comment: "i get those images in mipmap folder" -- that should only occur for launcher icons. Other sorts of image assets generate drawables.