# How to change application icon in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, cross-platform, xamarin.forms

I replaced all the images everywhere (by this I mean in drawable folders and all Windows Assets folders and iOS Resources folder), but it still shows me the default Xamarin icon for the app. I tried this code, too, but it doesn't seem to work either. Can someone tell me the solution?

```
[assembly: Application(Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
```

Comment: This code only works for Android. Be sure that you have cleaned your project and rebuilt it. It may also help to delete the app from your simulator/device and let it reinstall.

Comment: It doesn't work for Android in my application. My Android devices show the default Xamarin icon (a tablet and a phone). I tried reinstalling but my custon icon still doesn't appear.

Comment: That is weird, if you have replaced all the icons it should work. For Android check every subfolder under `resources`, for iOS check every file under `resources`.

Comment: I don't know why, for the life of me, doesn't Visual Studio add a simple UI feature for changing the app icon!? It has to be done in nearly every app, I don't understand why the process is to this day so complex

Answer (score 54):

### Updating Icon and Name (Android)

If you changed the icon file name please ensure you update the `Icon` reference in `MainActivity.cs`:

```
[Activity(Label = "MyName", Icon = "@mipmap/myicon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme"]    
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{ 
}
```

You should also update the names of `icon.xml` and `icon_round.xml` in the `mipmap-anydpi` folder to match to new icon name. If `launcher-foreground.png` was renamed then update the value of `<foreground...>` in corresponding `icon.xml`.

### Summary (Android)

1. Replace the `png`'s in mipmap folders with your new icon
2. If name was changed, update `Icon` value in `MainActivity.cs`
3. If name was changed, update name of (or create a new copy of) `icon.xml` and `icon_round.xml`
4. If name of `launcher-foreground.png` was changed then update value in `icon.xml`. Eg:

   ```xml
   <adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <background android:drawable="@color/my_launcher_background"/>
     <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/my_launcher_foreground"/>
   </adaptive-icon>
   ```
5. If name wasn't changed and you've cleaned and re-built project but still your new icons are not deploying: Delete `obj` folder from Android project directory

### Details and Issues if not updating (Android)

Xamarin Forms/Android puts 2 icons in each mipmap folder (mipmap-mdpi, mipmap-hdpi, mipmap-xhdpi, etc) - `icon.png` and `launcher-foreground.png`.

[image]

Replace both these images in each of the mipmap folders.  I kept the same names but it should be possible to use a different name.

If you **rename** `launcher-foreground.png` then you **must** update the values in `icon.xml` and `icon_round.xml` (or their equivalent new names). The value in the `<foreground...>` tag references the icon/png.  So, if `launcher-foreground.png` was updated to `my_launcher-foreground.png` this should be reflected in the `icon.xml` (see step 4 in summary above).

If the icons **still don't update even after cleaning/re-building** it could be that the original/default icons still existed in the Android project `obj` folder.  The solution is to **delete the `obj`** folder from the Android project directory.

---

### iOS

For iOS, please see [Managing Icons with Asset Catalogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/app-icons?tabs=windows#managing-icons-with-asset-catalogs).  A summary taken from the linked page is provided below:

> For icons, a special `AppIcon` image set can be added to the `Assets.xcassets` file in the app's project.
>
> To use an Asset Catalog, do the following:
>
> 1. Double-click the Info.plist file in the Solution Explorer.
> 2. Click on the Visual Assets tab and click on the Use Asset Catalog button under App Icons.
> 3. From the Solution Explorer, expand the Asset Catalog folder.
> 4. Double-click the Media file to open it in the editor.
> 5. Under the Properties Explorer the developer can select the different types and sizes of icons required.
> 6. Click on given icon type and select an image file for the required type/size.
> 7. Click the Open button to include the image in the project and set it in the xcasset.

---

### MacOs

The guide for MacOs is [Application icon for Xamarin.Mac apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/deploy-test/app-icon).  You need to consider the following steps:

> 1. Required image sizes and filenames
> 2. Packaging the icon resources
> 3. Using the icon

detailed in the linked docs above.

Comment: How about MacOS?

Answer (score 37):

For Android try to set the icon app like this:

```
[Activity(Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
{
     .....
}
```

Make sure that you have changed all the icon images on all drawable folders ( drawable, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi and drawable-xxhdpi ).

For iOS I like set the app icons and splash screen with Asset Catalogs, here you can find a guide to how to use it:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/app-icons/

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28065664/238419), app icons should go in `@mipmap/` folders, not `@drawable/`

Answer (score 15):

For iOS in visual studio...

Step1: Generate all the app icons from https://appicon.co/

Step2: In solution explorer, under iOS project, expand 'Asset Catalogs' and double click on 'Assests'. You can change the existing 'AppIcon' icons or Add a new Asset and attach the icons.

[image]

This is how you add a new asset...

[image]

Step3: In solution explorer, under iOS project, double click on Info.plist.
       Go to 'Visual Assets' tab, click on 'App Icons' and change the 'Source' to the 
       asset that you just created.

Done.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Somehow, and I can't remember how, Visual Studio 2019 generated the entire set of scaled bitmaps for me.  Still trying to figure out what I did, but that generation tool in the URL you mentioned seems to be integrated into VS2019.

Comment: This definitely did it for me, thank you so much! :). I found I was actually able to 'Import...' the assets made at the website you linked (tho I had to rename the existing one to 'OldAppIcons' first) after I unzipped the archive to a temp folder. Awesome!

Answer (score 8):

**Answer is deprecated**

If I understood you correctly, for iOS project: *Properties* -> *iOS Application*

For Android: *Properties* -> *Android Manifest*

Comment: Unfortunately I can only control the solutions on Android, and I have the required setting that you have shown, but there is still the default icon, not my one. I tried doing it with the same and different file name (icon.png/ic_launcher.png) but neither worked.

Comment: This answer may be outdated now, the `iOS Application` left pane doesn't exist any more in my current version of VSforMac. Maybe same happens for VisualStudio for Windows?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, but the following helped resolve it:

1. Go to ***MainActivity.cs*** (in the Solution Explorer)
2. Look for where it says ***'Icon ='***
3. **Change the location** of the Icon, but don't include the extension, i.e. jpg, png, etc. (For ex. Icon = "@drawable/weatherIcon")
4. **Save** the file
5. **Restart debugging** (the little restart icon beside the stop and pause icon around the top right-hand side of your screen)

If you get stuck on any part of this check out this short video from 02:47 onwards https://youtu.be/5g8lWPQZFxs?t=167. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Try to replace all the icon on iOS project > Properties > iOS Application > Iphone Icons/IPad Icons.
I change all of them, the settings icon do change. Images that on Resouces can be created by just insert images on there.

Answer (score 1):

Tested this today and noticed that you only need to change the icon images in all drawable folders,

```
              drawable,
              drawable-hdpi,
              drawable-xhdpi
              drawable-xxhdpi.
```

Depending on the device it's going to use different images. For me i used "Visual Studio Android Emulator" using:

```
              - 5" KitKat(4,4) XXHDPI Phone (Android 4,4 - API 19)
```

Did not need to uninstall and reinstall the app in the emulator, it updated on it's own after starting the project with "build" checked in the menu Build/Configuration manager.

On top of that no code changes were made!

Comment: what do you mean with "drawable folders"?

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the Icon.png and still nothing changed on the device, than change "Copy to Output Directory" propertiy to "Copy if newer" or "Copy always".
That was my solution.

Answer (score 0):

All of these solutions are great, but

## THE SIMPLEST WAY:

You can now just use [ResizetizerNT](https://github.com/Redth/ResizetizerNT)'s nuget package and upload one svg file and set IsAppIcon to true. That should generate everything needed.
If the existing app icon is icon.png, just name the svg to icon.svg and it should automatically work.

Alternatively, you can also add another SVG for the background in order to support adaptive icons on Android.

Context: ResizetizerNT was created by the Xamarin.Forms/MAUI Engineering Manager, Jonathan Dick