# Xamarin.Mac - Show icon/image before Window Title

Tags: c#, cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I am trying to show an image/icon before the title of window, just like in finder. I have used `Window.SetTitleWithRepresentedFilename` but it just shows a generic icon not that png file I want to show.[image]

Comment: Maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37945767/how-to-change-application-icon-in-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public override void WindowDidLoad()
{
    base.WindowDidLoad();

    Window.RepresentedUrl = new NSUrl(Path.GetFullPath("check.png"));
    var btn = Window.StandardWindowButton(NSWindowButton.DocumentIconButton);
    btn.Image = NSImage.ImageNamed("check");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show a PNG with this. It shows the finder icon for the type of the file you are pointing to (not the tumbnail). If you put the users home folder in it will show the little 'house' icon

Comment: Found a way to achieve this. Check my answer below.