# XAML add logo to Xamarin Crossplatform form

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

How do i add logo to center of the Xaml Form, i am starting out Xamarin.

My xaml code looks something like this :

```
    <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="50" VerticalOptions="Center">  
        <Entry Placeholder="Mail id"></Entry>  
        <Entry Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True"></Entry>  
        <Button Text="Log In" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="##ff77D065"></Button> </StackLayout>  
</ContentPage>
```

This works fine, Now i want to see where i can add the logo to the Xaml form, Its cross platform.

I am new to this.

**Edit**

Trying out something like this

```
<StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="50" VerticalOptions="Center">
             VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="10">
    <Image Source="screenimg2.png" x:Name="imgLogo" HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="150"/>  
    <Entry Placeholder="Mail id"></Entry>  
    <Entry Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True"></Entry>  
    <Button Text="Log In" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="##ff77D065"></Button> 
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37945767/how-to-change-application-icon-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: use an `Image` control

Comment: @Jason , Do u mean something like that on Edits? Pls see edit ?

Comment: @Sam Are you trying to center the `Image` and than overlay all the other controls on top of a page centered image?

Comment: @SushiHangover, yes

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `AbsoluteLayout` to contain your "background" logo and then the `StackLayout`, both centered on screen and then place your UI widgets inside the `StackLayout` to control the order of their placement:

#### Example (Logo is set to a 25% opacity):

```
<AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="Black">
    <Image Source="logo.png" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,.5,.75,.75" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Opacity=".25" />
    <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  >
        <Label Text="INTRO TO THE WORLD" TextColor="Green" />
        <Entry Text="Some Entry Text" BackgroundColor="Green" />
    </StackLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

[image]

re: [Xamarin.Forms AbsoluteLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout)