# App icon is not changing in Xamarin forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, icons

I have a PNG icon file named icon.png and I want to use it as my Xamarin.Form app's icon. So here's what I've done -

- Changed Application Icon from **Android Options**
- Changed `Icon = "@mipmap/icon"` in `MainActivity.cs` file

Still it was showing the default Xamarin logo icon. Then I did the followings -

- Changed `<foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/icon" />` in `icon.xml` file
- Changed `<foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/icon" />` in `icon_round.xml` file

Now the default android icon is showing but not my icon. What to do? Please help.

I tried matching all the icons dimension to the default icons dimension, also tried the followings -
36px for idpi, 48px for mdpi, 72px for hdpi, 96px for xhdpi, 144px for xxhdpi

I also tried restarting VS, rebuilding the entire solution, clearing cache and temp files.

Comment: I've already did that. I think I've mentioned it in the question body.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37945767/how-to-change-application-icon-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: I followed this too, didn't work.

Comment: @MahmudulHasan Normally, we reset the application icon using `Icon = "@mipmap/icon"`. This way works well on my side. Could you try to use a small  icon file to test?

Comment: You mean a file with smaller size? My icon is approximately ~20kb.

Comment: The way i provided works well for me. Could you provide a example which uploads on GitHub for me to reproduce?

Comment: https://github.com/MahmudX/SchoolApp here is the project link. @WendyZang-MSFT

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have checked the code sample. Do the changes below it would change the application icon.

Change the icon in MainActivity:

```
 Icon = "@drawable/logo"
```

Change the Application icon in Android Manifest:

[image]

**Sceenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Okay, now this actually helps. Thanks.