# Why every image I add to my app is in small size?

Tags: android, image, imageview, android-mipmap

When I'm trying adding images to my app, the size of the image is always small - like a little icon. How can I change it? The original size of my image is big. I have no idea why the Android Studio makes it small.

When I add the image I add by these steps:

RightClick on Res(folder) --> new --> Image Asset --> I choose Launcher Icons.

And when I add the image to an ImageView I can't see an option which allows me to change the size of the image.

[image]

Comment: change the directory to res -> drawables

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with your `Layout` file design...

Comment: Place your images in drawable or mipmaps folder with corresponding sizes http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html

Comment: mmm `mipmap` it's only for icons if I understand correctly in google developers...

Comment: I've placed my images in a mipmap folder. So how do I upload a large sized image?

Comment: Really, read me... The mipmap folders are for placing your app/launcher icons (which are shown on the homescreen) in only. Any other drawable assets you use should be placed in the relevant drawable folders as before. @olash12345

Comment: you need to place your image resource file in drawables. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065267/mipmap-vs-drawable-folders

Comment: if you think that mipmap is only for icons, then please refactor and move the image to drawable folder and check it

Comment: Simply use drawable resources folder, mipmap used for holding your launcher icons only.

Comment: @Aspicas ok, But when I try adding images to the drawable folder (right click, new, image asset) , the Android Studio adds the image automatically to the mipmap folder for some reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your Images to drawable folder of your Project. Image Asset tool is for adding images for icons (Action bar icons, Launcher Icon or Notification Icons), refer to this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html) to understand what is Asset Image tool. Also bare in mind that a good practise is to use many same images with different resolutions (mdpi - hdpi - xdpi - xxdpi - xxxdpi) in order to support different resolutions for android devices, you can refer to this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should place your image in the drawable folder, but follow the same steps besides that. It should resolve your issue.