# After change navigation drawer item's icon, app is dead

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I downloaded icons for navigation drawer items at [here](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/) 
And I changed my drawer item icons. And then, I tried to run my app. 
But, my app is not working. It was fine before change icons.

I just moved `xml` files of icons to `drawable-v21` folder.

> Here is the message.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hsk.hallymexam, PID: 11979
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

    {com.hsk.hallymexam/com.hsk.hallymexam.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.hsk.hallymexam.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5580)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.hsk.hallymexam.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5580) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020050
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2326)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:321)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:192)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:421)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.prepareMenuItems(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:495)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.update(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:436)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:112)
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateMenu(NavigationView.java:245)
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:169)
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:95)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.hsk.hallymexam.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5580) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: you are using vector drawables (xml files) for icons..right?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? There might be multiple reasons. Maybe its about the Android version your device is running. Vector drawables (if you used such drawables) are not supported directly on older Androids (but there is a support library for that). Further, you state that you placed your icons within the 21 folder, making them available only on API level 21 devices. Is your device running on level 21?

Comment: @OnkarNene Yes right.

Comment: @Baschi you are right. it was API level problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, as other people suggesting **don't place your icons in mipmap** folder. It is a specific folder only for application icon. Place all you icons in **drawable** folders.

Second, check your drawable folder. If your icons only placed in **drawable-v21** then you have a problem, because **drawable-v21** used only for devices with api level >= 21. Just replace them to **drawable** folder

Third, if you using vector graphics and want to support devices with api level < 21, you need to enable **supporting of vector drawables**. [More info here](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)

Comment: Thanks... It was API level problem. so shame

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all drawer icon into `drawable-hdpi`,`drawable-mdpi`,`drawable-xhdpi` `drawable-xxhdpi` and `drawable-xxxhdpi` folder

Comment: he is using vector drawables.

Comment: @OnkarNene but I see he said `I downloaded icons for navigation drawer items`

Comment: at the end he said "I just moved xml files of icons to drawable-v21 folder." so i thought he is using vector drawables.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for this exception:

1. Icon size too large (in pixels)
   Solution : All your drawables used in navigation drawer and other icons should be atmost of 48*48 pixel size.
2. Improper reference to drawable
   Solution : First copy the image (which follows solution-1) and then in android studio, paste it in the drawable root folder.
3. Improper support of SVG
   Solution : follow [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html#running) link

> All your XML drawables should be stored in drawables root folder and not in size specific sub folders for better results.
>
> If you are using SVG files, then follow the link i mentioned above, copying XML files to another API specific folder directly will only increase your problem

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you are using Android Studio IDE

1) If you are using **png / jpg** icons then put your icons in respective mipmap folder i.e, `mipmap-hdpi`, `mipmap-xhdpi`, etc. & then reference it as `@mipmap/YOUR_ICON_NAME`

2) If you are using **XML (vector drawables)**  files for icons then put your all `xml`(vector drawables) files in `drawable` folder instead of `drawable-v21` and then reference it as `@drawable/YOUR_XML_FILE_NAME`

Hope it will help :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28065664/5471104,
this might help to restrict the use of mipmap folder for other drawables.