# Successful build but the app keeps crashing - android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-debug

I started to develop an android application, and I'm following tutorials. After I developed the first layout and launched the emulator. I get an "App X has stopped" error.
Thanks

```
07-19 16:35:19.113 8380-8380/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
07-19 16:35:19.364 8380-8380/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
07-19 16:35:19.554 8380-8387/? I/zygote: Debugger is no longer active
07-19 16:35:20.591 8380-8380/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
07-19 16:35:30.584 8380-8391/ma.ac.iav.equineupperrespiratoryguide I/zygote: NativeAllocBackground concurrent copying GC freed 2710(1039KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 70% free, 656KB/2MB, paused 2.481ms total 420.596ms
07-19 16:35:30.857 8380-8391/ma.ac.iav.equineupperrespiratoryguide I/zygote: NativeAllocBackground concurrent copying GC freed 76(32KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 70% free, 646KB/2MB, paused 13.672ms total 91.301ms
07-19 16:35:31.040 8380-8391/ma.ac.iav.equineupperrespiratoryguide I/zygote: NativeAllocBackground concurrent copying GC freed 57(43KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 70% free, 635KB/2MB, paused 5.447ms total 41.602ms
07-19 16:35:31.094 8380-8512/ma.ac.iav.equineupperrespiratoryguide D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
07-19 16:35:31.310 8380-8512/ma.ac.iav.equineupperrespiratoryguide I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-19 16:35:31.310 8380-8512/ma.ac.iav.equineupperrespiratoryguide D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
07-19 16:35:31.314 8380-8512/ma.ac.iav.equineupperrespiratoryguide W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
07-19 16:35:31.314 8380-8512/ma.ac.iav.equineupperrespiratoryguide D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
07-19 16:35:31.370 8380-8512/ma.ac.iav.equineupperrespiratoryguide D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa0d05480: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
07-19 16:35:31.479 8380-8512/ma.ac.iav.equineupperrespiratoryguide D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0d05480: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0d03220)
07-19 16:35:31.660 8380-8380/ma.ac.iav.equineupperrespiratoryguide D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


--------- beginning of crash
07-19 16:35:31.676 8380-8380/ma.ac.iav.equineupperrespiratoryguide 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ma.ac.iav.equineupperrespiratoryguide, PID: 8380
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(114307200bytes) bitmap.
    at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:229)
    at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:97)
    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:529)
    at android.view.View.getDrawableRenderNode(View.java:19381)
    at android.view.View.drawBackground(View.java:19317)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19114)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18073)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19126)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:785)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18073)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:643)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:649)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:757)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2980)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2794)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2347)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArg

sCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

[the layout design app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfltS.png)
[the xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTLlP.png)

Image of the emulator pop up text

[image: image of the emulator pop up text]

[logcat crashing text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuGxv.png)

[logcat crashing text 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2FZy.png)

[logcat crashing text 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M72ds.png)

Comment: Please add the entire error stack trace from the logcat to your post... but not as an image. Add the text

Comment: Hello there and welcome to Stack Overflow. You've come to the right place seeking help if your app keeps crashing. However, the information you have provided us, the pictures and the supporting text you wrote, don't seem to give a whole lot of information about what's really going on inside of your program. It's good to post pieces of source code or a working example that other users can play with or analyze. You also seem to have not captured the entire logcat output, so we can't see where the stacktrace ends (or begins); this is pretty important stuff. Try adding that!

Comment: @Zimano Hey guys .i've added the text of the crash ..the layout design and xml file ..thanks

Comment: @ErrahbiZouhair You posted the same image twice, did you mean for it to be two different pictures? It's better if you would just paste the text in your post, and format it as code. `Like this`.

Comment: @Zimano Done, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image you're uploading is too large. Look into using a library like Glide or Picasso to load the image and it will resize it for you so you stop going out of memory or loading an image that doesn't fit. You could write the code yourself but these libraries have already solved the problem.

Comment: the size of the background and the icons in total is 0.5Mo . is that too much?

Comment: Yeah you were right! after i have removed the backgroung and downgrade the quality of the pictures! the app did worked! Thanks dude

Answer (score 1):

Solution : Try moving the (hi-res) splash bitmap from drawable to drawable-xxhdpi.

Similar problem : Refer this link

[“Canvas: trying to draw too large bitmap”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39111248/canvas-trying-to-draw-too-large-bitmap-when-android-n-display-size-set-larger)

Comment: i did tried the previous solution, i reduced the size and the quality of the picture and the app did worked! thanks for the answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer .. worked smoothly  :)