# Not have drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi

Tags: android-studio, drawable, image-resizing, dpi, android-mipmap

WorkSpace:**Android Studio**

I have 35 images.
I have realized that I have drawable *(but not have "drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi..")* folder and also there are *"mipmap-mdpi.."* folders.

1. **I put my images to the simple drawable folder. --> It gives me error: "Canvas trying to draw too large bitmap" *I search little bit and I found* ["Canvas: trying to draw too large bitmap" when Android N Display Size set larger than Small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39111248/canvas-trying-to-draw-too-large-bitmap-when-android-n-display-size-set-larger) that someone in the link said that I should move images to the *"drawable-xhdpi"* folder. I tried to move my images to the *"mipmap-xhdpi"* as you  might be know I don't have any type of drawable folders. Only *drawable* I have.**
2. **I wanted to use "mipmap" folders for "Images."** It works now but maybe it is not best practice
3. **After that I have search it little bit and I found [Mipmaps vs. drawable folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065267/mipmaps-vs-drawable-folders)
   and someone answered (878 up vote) that mipmap folders is for icons.**

**What Should I do?**

1. **Resize the images and put it back to the *drawable***
2. **Do not move your images to the *drawable* again, it can stay in the *mipmap* folder no problem. The person in the link said wrong.**

Thank you for your attention.

**And very very important and last question is should i resize one image into 4 , and put one of them into mdpi, one of them hdpi, one of them xhdpi and one of them xxhdpi?** if yes , it means if i have 30 images, i should resize and make it 120 images?

Comment: Have you found an answer to this? I also only have a drawable folder and was wondering if the others were still needed?

Comment: Hi dear George, please create your own drawable folders on your own. because sometimes android studio doesn't create these folders it self. but do not create it randomly. search on youtube.com for : how to create drawable xhdpi folder android studio. Sincerely Rashad Nasirli