# Cannot Find Drawable Directory in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am trying to open Asset Studio in Android.  My textbook says to right-click on the drawable directory.  Where can I find the drawable directory?

Here is a link to a screenshot of the folders in my res directory

[image: Res Folders]

Comment: Click on "res" directory

Comment: Then from there click "new>image asset"?

Comment: instead of drawable you have mimap. Just create drawable folder for each density inside you project structure and you are good to go.

Comment: you have selected project files at the top.Change that to project

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28065664/3701433

Comment: @kgandroid selecting project files also showed my drawables folder.

Comment: Project, not project files is selected.  I am a very new Android programmer so how do you create a drawable folder in each density?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new `drawable` folder.

Right click on res > New > Directory.

Name it as "drawable".

[image: drawable]

If you want to add `drawable` folders for different densities,

Right click on res > New > Android resource directory.

[image]

In the window that appears write "Directory name" as drawable. In the section under it choose "Density" and click on ">>" button. Enter the required density. hit Ok.

[image]

Comment: This actually solves the issue?  Do I have to do anything else with it?

Comment: Great!  Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

[image: sCREENsHOT]

1.Click on app folder
2.Then src
3.Then main
4.Then res
5.Then you can find the drawable folders

Make sure that **Project** is selected at the top.

Comment: That is what I thought but I am not seeing any drawable folders.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot in your question

Comment: Posted the screenshot

Comment: Simple go to any xml where drawable is used and press F3 on it. It will find files for you. Additionally Android studio have this "Scroll from source" button which directs you to file in project structure.

Comment: SEE UPDATED ANSWER

Comment: I could see drawable folder in my android studio even if project is not selected at top

Comment: Project is selected on the top.  Pressing F3 does nothing

Comment: you have selected project files at the top.Change that to project

Comment: then create a drawable folder manually inside res...but drawable folder should be created by default