# FCM - When setting icon in meta data, should I use the mipmap folder?

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-mipmap

To set a default icon with FCM we can add a meta tag in the Android manifest. Mine currently looks like below because I'd like to use my application's icon as the notification icon when receiving push notifications:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_logo_launcher" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Notice I am getting `ic_logo_launcher.png` from the mipmap folder. Is this advisable?

Comment: I place it in drawable check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065267/mipmap-vs-drawable-folders but still I think your question is very good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes ! You can ...though firebase takes app_icon by default

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/notificationBackground" />
```

But its better to use icon from @drawable which will have alpha and white icon.

Comment: ```Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:resource"'```

Comment: Hi I am new in android native, using FCM in ionic where to put meta tag in manifest.xml ?

Comment: Ionic is hybrid mode. I am not sure where to place.