# imageView not displaying in alertDialog

Tags: android, imageview, android-alertdialog

I have a pop up that I populate through my custom xml. I want an icon and next to the icon, I want a switch.
The custom xml looks has this code in it:

```
<!-- alertdialog_menu.xml -->
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_satellite_black_24dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <Switch
       android:id="@+id/satelliteSwitch"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="36dp"
       android:layout_weight="0.90"
       android:text="Satellite"
       android:textSize="22sp"/>
```

And this below is my java code that I use to display the popup.

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.alertdialog_menu, null);
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
alertDialogBuilder.create().show();
```

This is what I see:
[image]

I should see the icon imageView to the left of the satellite imageview, but instead I see empty white space.

Comment: Maybe add some color to it ?

Comment: Does not work :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `android:src="@mipmap/ic_satellite_black_24dp"` instead of `app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_satellite_black_24dp"`

Between, place your image to `drawable` folder, not `mipmap` folder. `Mipmap` folder is used to place your app/launcher `icons`.

To know the differences , check [mipmap vs drawable folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065267/mipmap-vs-drawable-folders).

Comment: Got it, works perfectly. Thank you! And I placed it inside drawable.