# What are the issues if we use Mipmap instead of Drawables

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, drawable, android-mipmap

As per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065267/mipmap-vs-drawable-folders) - The mipmap folders are for placing your app/launcher icons (which are shown on the homescreen) in only

My Question is : What problems one will face if the drawables are placed in mipmap instead of drawable?
 OR 
How will this impact my UI on various screens?

Comment: Things that expect drawable resource IDs may not work with `R.mipmap` values.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes I am aware of that, I want to know its impact on my UI on various screens.I've updated the question

Comment: "How will this impact my UI on various screens?" -- it shouldn't. Assuming that you can get the mipmap to load (see my previous comment), AFAIK it is visually indistinguishable from the equivalent drawable.