# which mipmap folder for 7 inch tablet to display proper image size

Tags: android, android-layout, tablet, android-mipmap

In my project i have to make layout for both 7 inch and 10 inch tablet . I have made `layout-sw600dp` and `layout-sw720dp` respectively, and for images `mipmap-xlarge-mdpi` folder . now for 7" tablet which image i.e mipmap folder i need to create so layout display proper. Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: You should use drawable folder instead of mipmap. Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065267/mipmap-vs-drawable-folders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out with `mipmap-large-mdpi` for 7" tablet screen . It works perfect.