# Android studio does not create drawable folder density wise

Tags: android

I created one project in android studio, android studio didn't create drawable folder density wise as like it used to `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-mdpi` etc. It created `mipmap-hdpi`, `mipmap-mdpi` etc.

I read https://stackoverflow.com/a/28065664/2455259 `mipmap` directory is for launcher icons.

> Any other drawable assets you use should be placed in the relevant drawable folders as before.

Then why Android Studio stopped to create drawable folder as like before ? Is it no longer recommended approach to put app resources in drawables ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It wants you to create them when you need them, you can create one by right clicking on the **res folder** and  then click on **add new resource directory**, select the **drawable as the resource type** and then from the list of **available qualifiers** chose d**ensity** and then the **>> button**, then select the density you want.

[image]
I think a reason why it was removed is for consistency because density is just one of the many qualifiers you can add to a resource file.

It also makes the folder structure neat, because you might not be using all the drawable folders.

The reason why it created the mipmap-hdpi, mipmap-mdpi folders is because there is already a file in it which is the default launcher icon for a new app, if there was no item in it it would not have created them.

Comment: I guess we always need `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi` etc

Comment: you'll never know

Answer (score 2):

The mipmap folder is used for icons only. The other resources have to be placed in correspond drawables' folders.
It is needed for better icon rendering.