# What's the right size for an Image Asset?

Tags: java, android, image, icons

I have a picture and want to use it as the app icon for my android app. I use the `ImageAsset` in `Android Studio` to create multiple icons for different phones, so I only need one picture.

My picture turned out too small (`144px x 144px`) and I cannot find information about the sizes on the developer pages.

Who can help me with this question?

Comment: According to Android's Docs: "512 x 512 pixel image [is] appropriate for the Google Play store" (https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio)

Comment: Yeah for the play store. But the icon is too small on the device

Comment: If they suggest 512x512 for playstore then it should be suitable for device also - this is their official documentation

Comment: you have to use vector icon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**"512 x 512 pixel image [is] appropriate for the Google Play store"**

To start Image Asset Studio, follow these steps:

1. In the Project window, select the [Android view](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/index.html#ProjectFiles).
2. Right-click the **res** folder and select **New > Image Asset**.

[image]

3. Continue by following the steps to:

   - If your app supports Android 8.0, create [adaptive and legacy launcher icons](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio#create-adaptive).
   - If your app supports versions no higher than Android 7.1, create a [legacy launcher icon only](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio#create-legacy).
   - Create an [action bar or tab icon](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio#create-actionbartab).
   - Create a [notification icon](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio#create-notification).

for more [detail](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Use `App Icon Creater` from `Android Studio`. Go to *File* -> *New* -> *Image Asset* and select `Launcher Icons`

Comment: Thats what I am doing. Exactly that. But the app icon turns out not well-sized

Comment: You can resize the icon, by switching the *Resize* scroll bar in that page.

Answer (score 0):

1/ The suitable place to but app launcher icons is `mipmap` folder, not `drawable` like other images. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065267/mipmaps-vs-drawable-folders), images in the mipmap folder use different resolutions from the device’s current density.

My `ic_launcher` in `mipmap-xxhdpi` is also 144x144 but it still looks good on my device

[image]

2/ Check your source image when creating an app logo with Image Asset tools. Use a high-resolution image for better result. I used a 512x512 image

Answer (score 0):

I would create separate images for each one:

```
LDPI should be 36 x 36.

MDPI should be 48 x 48.

TVDPI should be 64 x 64.

HDPI should be 72 x 72.

XHDPI should be 96 x 96.

XXHDPI should be 144 x 144.

XXXHDPI should be 192 x 192.
```

Then just put each of them in the separate stalks of the drawable folder.

You are also required to give a large version of your icon when uploading your app onto the Google Play Store and this should be `WEB 512 x 512`. This is so large so that Google can rescale it to any size in order to advertise your app throughout the Google Play Store and not add pixelation to your logo.

Basically, all of the other icons should be in proportion to the 'baseline' icon, `MDPI at 48 x 48`.

```
LDPI is MDPI x 0.75.

TVDPI is MDPI x 1.33.

HDPI is MDPI x 1.5.

XHDPI is MDPI x 2.

XXHDPI is MDPI x 3.

XXXHDPI is MDPI x 4.
```

This is all explained on the Iconography page of the Android Developers website:
http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Answer (score 0):

196 is a right side of android icon,create 196 icon side and create multiple images.