# What "Icon Type" should I choose for normal images to be used in an Android app? How should I add these as ImageViews?

Tags: android, image, android-studio, android-imageview, android-asset-studio

I want the images to be as they are, without any changes. I'm trying to add some images provided by Android Studio by default (Asset Type: Clip Art).

The images will be used as `ImageView`s in the app's main screen and nowhere else. It won't be used for any notifications, as the app's (launcher) icon or as Action Bar/Tab icons. What "Icon Type" should I choose for normal images to be used in an Android smartphone (not an Android TV) app's activity?

[image]

Is this the best way to create images for an app? Also, when I'm adding these images as `ImageView`s, should I choose the one from the `Drawable` or `Mip Map` tab?

Drawable:

[image]

Mip Map:

[image]

I guess [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28065664/16136190) says it's Drawable as Mip Map is only for launcher icons. But, which one do I choose if it's the Drawable tab that I have to choose from? What if I want the image with *both* its background and foreground? I actually wouldn't care choosing the *wrong* option if the image looks as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TO get images from clip art to be used in your app go to drawable>vector asset> select your clickart> click on finish.

The better way however is to go online and download .svg files for icons and then select local svg option in your vector asset creator to use it in your app.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I couldn't find any answer telling which "Icon Type" to choose... the question is also probably specifically about Launcher Icons and their background properties, but that's not my main question... Could you please link which answer exactly it's?

Comment: Sorry maybe i misunderstood you.. please check the updated answer

Comment: No! Did I mention it wrongly? Sorry if I've, but I'm not trying to create Launcher Icons (logos) for my app. Or, are you saying that I should create a Vector Asset in my project's Drawable folder?

Comment: RIght.. I 'll delete the upper part. Yes .. Right click there to create your assets to be used in the app

Comment: Oh, but why Vector Assets instead of Drawables?

Comment: because vector assets are more optimized than your traditional jpg or png files.